# Number of permutations for card decks in "Skat" and "Doppelkopf" games

Tags: combinatorics, card-games

In the card game [Skat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skat_%28card_game%29), you play with a deck of $32$ cards and each of the three players gets $10$ cards.

This means that there are $32! \approx 2.63 × 10^{35}$ possible permutations of the card deck.

And for each player's hand of $10$ cards, there may be ${{32}\choose{10}} \cdot 10! = 234,102,016,512,000$ possibilities, if this is really a partial permutation.

Is this correct?

---

But in the related card game [Doppelkopf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doppelkopf) ("double-head"), you play with *two* decks of $24$ cards each. So you have two queens of clubs, for example, which you cannot distinguish. Each player gets 12 cards.

How do you calculate the numbers in this case? Do we have to divide the number of permutations like this?

$$ \frac{48!}{2!^{24}} \approx 7.39 × 10^{53} $$

And what about the possibilities per each player's hand? I have no idea for that one.

Comment: For a hand of a player, you just pick 10 cards out of 32 (order does not matter) so we get $\binom{32}{10}$, not $10!$ as many.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Thank you! I guess your calculation does not pay attention to the order (which makes sense with cards on one's hand). Is my own calculation at least correct for the case where the order is crucial?

Comment: Yes, if the order would matter, we would get $\binom{32}{10} \cdot 10! = \frac{32!}{22!}$, which are often called the number of permutations of 10 from 32, e.g. If order does not matter, it's called the number of 10-combinations from 32, or some such term. The Doppelkopf case is more complicated.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Thanks for explaining these! Obviously, your solution is the correct one :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the problem in this way: you have 24 distinct cards and you allow the same card to be drawn twice, but not more. Thus the number ways to pick 12 cards (assuming order doesn't matter, as is usual with card hands) is the number of solutions to the equation $$x_1 + x_2 + ... + x_{24} = 12$$ where each $x_i$ can be $0$, $1$, or $2$. If one considers the expansion of
$$ (1 + x + x^2)^{24} $$ one may determine that the coefficient of $x^{12}$ is the number of solutions to the above equation. By applying the binomial theorem twice, one finds
$$(1+ x + x^2)^{24} = \sum_{k=0}^{24}\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{24}{n}\binom{n}{k}x^{48-2n+k}$$
$x^{48 - 2n + k}$ is $x^{12}$ when $k = 2n - 36$. Since $k ≥ 0$ and $n ≤ 24$, the only solutions $(n, k)$ to this equation are $(18, 0)$, $(19, 2)$, $(20, 4)$, $(21, 6)$, $(22, 8)$, $(23, 10)$, and $(24, 12)$. Therefore, the coefficient of $x^{12}$ is 
$$\binom{24}{18}\binom{18}{0} + \binom{24}{19}\binom{19}{2} + \binom{24}{20}\binom{20}{4} + \binom{24}{21}\binom{21}{6} + \binom{24}{22}\binom{22}{8} + \binom{24}{23}\binom{23}{10} + \binom{24}{24}\binom{24}{12}$$

which becomes $$ 134596 + 42504 * 171 + 10626 * 4845 + 2024 * 54264 + 276 * 319770 + 24 * 1144066 + 2704156 = 287134346 \approx 2.87 * 10^8$$

So there are about $2.87 * 10^8$ possible hands for some player playing Doppelkopf.

As for your first question, there are $48!$ permutations, but some of these are indistinguishable. Consider two indistinguishable permutations to be 'equivalent.' In each permutation, there are 24 pairs of duplicates. One may switch any of these pairs and get an equivalent permutation. There are $2^{24} \approx 1.68 * 10^7$ possible ways to choose which pairs to rearrange, so each set of equivalent permutations contains $2^{24}$ total permutations. Thus, the number of distinguishable permutations is as you said $\frac{48!}{2^{24}} \approx 7.40 * 10^{53}$.